# Logging file output

Tags: powershell

The logging only traps on the IDs in my text file (get-content) it does not print the file name which gets copied

I've tried using the log option with robocopy however it only logs the last enter in my get-content text file

```
$Source = "F:\Temp\"
$Test = "F:\Output\"
$Daily_Results="F:\Output\Test\"

foreach ($ID in Get-Content F:\Files\files.txt) {
    $ID
    Get-ChildItem -Path $Source | foreach {
        if($_ -match $ID)  { 
            $Path=$Source+"$_\"
            $Path
            robocopy $path $test 
            Write-Host $Path
           "File copied"
            Write-Output $ID "File copied" | Out-File $Daily_Results\$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd)_CopyMove_Results.txt -append
            Write-Output $_ | Out-File $Daily_Results\$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd)_CopyMove_Results.txt -append
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us what the `$ID` is from the text file. Is that the full filename, the file's BaseName, some code that must be present in the file name of maybe more like a Filter ('*.pdf') for instance?

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that `$_` gets you the full object, you need to explicitly say you want the `Name`.

```
Write-Output $_.Name | Out-File $Daily_Results\$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd)_CopyMove_Results.txt -append
```

Comment: It didn't work... It just logged the Folder and not the file within the folder which was copied

Comment: I got the code working.  Added Recurse to the GCI and using the $_.Name variable as suggested.  Why is it giving this error before copying every file (the file is there)    "2019/11/06 20:58:55 ERROR 2 (0x00000002) Accessing Source Directory"

Comment: Most likely this line `$Path=$Source+"$_\"` is what is getting you in trouble, try to change it to use the `join-path` cmdlet

Comment: How would I use that function?

Comment: If you use `get-help join-path -ShowWindow` you will get the examples you need on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

As you are copying the files one-by-one, I see no real advantage in using robocopy here, but rather user PowerShell's own `Copy-Item` cmdlet.

Because you didn't say what the `$ID` from the text file could be, from the code you gave I gather that it is some string that must be part of the file name to copy.

This should work for you then

```
$Source        = 'F:\Temp'
$Destination   = 'F:\Output'
$Daily_Results = Join-Path -Path 'F:\Output\Test' -ChildPath ('{0:yyyy-MM-dd}_CopyMove_Results.txt' -f (Get-Date))

foreach ($ID in Get-Content F:\Files\files.txt) {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -File -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "*$ID*" } | ForEach-Object {
        $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $Destination -Force
        Write-Host  "File '$($_.Name)' copied"
        # output to the log file
        "$ID File copied: '$($_.Name)'" | Out-File -FilePath $Daily_Results -Append
    }
}
```